# Token expiry time from ServiceBusClient class of Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-sdk-.net

If I create a ServiceBusClient using the Sas Token Method, is there a way(property) to get the token expiry time from the ServiceBusClient object? Because, I will discard the token and down the timeline, I want to be able to identify the expiry and refresh it before it throws the token expiry error.

Comment: Gaurav's answer is correct; we do not expose the token nor its properties from the client.  The assumption is that since your application passed the token to the Service Bus library, it participated in the creation of that token and understands the properties used to generate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the `ServiceBusClient` documentation [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusclient?view=azure-dotnet), it is not possible to extract the token expiry time from the instance of that object.

This is something you will need to handle on your own.