# Does Microsoft Azure have a similar construct to MuleSoft Object Store?

Tags: azure, access-token, external, mulesoft, persistent-object-store

I want to track external tokens for API access in an Azure program.

MuleSoft, my previous ESB,  lets me place values like a token in the "Object Store v2" and to set date/time expiry.  Once the value removes itself after expiration, my process detects the missing token, retrieves a fresh token, and places it back in the object store which resets its timer.  It's efficient, and I renew tokens only after they "self-destruct".

Does a similar capacity (self-deleting data and the ability to query it) exist in the Azure?  I know I could create a DB process, but I hope for something simpler.

To be clear, these are not Azure tokens.  I don't need to worry about Azure itself.  This is for tracking tokens to access entities like Saleforce and eBay.

Comment: "Azure" is a big thing but if we limit this to Azure service bus, I don't see any evidence of it supporting this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2018/march/azure-enterprise-data-integration-patterns-with-azure-service-bus this also seems to indicate that what you're after is not a native function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70782350/token-expiry-time-from-servicebusclient-class-of-azure-messaging-servicebus

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Azure Cache for Redis`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-overview). It is a in-memory, key-value like datastore that is similar to mule's object store.
It provides even better flexibility since you can manage the TTL for each key (in mule object store you have to provide it at the object store level).

Storing tokens is a common use case for redis cache